# Как реализовать загрузку файлов с возможностью их удалить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть input type file с атрибутом multiple. Как можно реализовать удаление файлов которые мы загрузили? 
Пример на скриншоте.[image: Пример загрузки файла]

Comment: загрузка идет сразу на сервер, или есть "песочница", после которой юзеру надо нажать Load file(s) ?

Comment: В любом случае, после загрузки файла, сервер в ответ должен не просто говорить "ok/bad", а ещё и возвращать некий id. Тогда операция удаления стает тривиальной.

Comment: Файлы должны отправляться после нажатия кнопки Submit

Comment: Думаю вы ищете это https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File